# How do I get rid of unwanted pipe symbols in a pipe delimited field - Linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have an unusual one here.
We have a pipe delimited file with headers but in the 9th field (which picks up user input) we can occasionally get a user typing in the pipe symbol.
This throws the formatting of the file completely out of the window as the number of pipe symbols now don't match the headers.
See below for example - it's the 5th entry under the EVNT_MSSG header:

```
IDS|STG   |STT|WRKLST  |AR|CD   |DT    |INDX|EVNT_MSSG                                |EVNT_SRC|EVNT_TM |TYP|DATE    |USR_ID|IDS_APP
1  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|14|BM404|202302|15  |This is some text                        |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
2  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|15|BM501|202302|16  |This is some more                        |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
3  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|16|BM502|202302|17  |This bit is all good                     |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
4  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|17|BM551|202302|18  |Yet more text                            |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
5  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|18|EM002|202302|19  |problem here | pipes | not needed | Call |Operator|10:33:14|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
6  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|19|BM451|202302|20  |This is also fine                        |Operator|10:33:14|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
```

Aparrently, changing this at source would incur a cost the company is not will to pay so I've been tasked with coming up with a solution to get rid of the pipe symbols in the 9th field only whilst leaving every other field intact.

I've hit a brick wall unfortunatley.

I'm using the | as a file separator in awk to pull the 9th field ie

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[|]+" } ; { print $9 }'
```

but the pipes are throwing this out as they see the first unwanted pipe as the next legitimate separator. I think I may have to approach this from a different angle but haven't got the foggiest where to go with it.
Any help on this would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like your customer should either be blocked by inputting a unwanted character, or you should escape it

Comment: Are fields of fixed size?

Comment: @mouviciel probably not since `EVNT_MSSG` is supposed to be user input. But perhaps that info can be derived from the header line.

Comment: so what happens when the user starts entering newline characters?

Comment: @jhnc : that's what those extra pipes represent - `"\n"` but shown as `" | "`

Comment: Fields are not fixed size, not come across user entering newlines yet (emphasis on the yet)

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this approach would suit?

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}                                      # set field separator to pipe
     NF == 15 {print}                                   # if number of fields is correct, print the line
     NF > 15 {                                          # if NF is greater than expected i.e. extra pipes in $9
         for (i=1;i<=8; i++) {printf "%s|", $i}         # print the first 8 fields
         for (j=9; j<=(NF-6); j++) {printf "%s", $j}    # print the next N fields without a pipe delimiter
         for (k=(NF-5); k<=NF; k++) {printf "|%s", $k}  # print the last 6 fields
         print ""                                       # print a newline
     }' file
```

Applied to your example data:

```
IDS|STG   |STT|WRKLST  |AR|CD   |DT    |INDX|EVNT_MSSG                                |EVNT_SRC|EVNT_TM |TYP|DATE    |USR_ID|IDS_APP
1  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|14|BM404|202302|15  |This is some text                        |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
2  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|15|BM501|202302|16  |This is some more                        |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
3  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|16|BM502|202302|17  |This bit is all good                     |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
4  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|17|BM551|202302|18  |Yet more text                            |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
5  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|18|EM002|202302|19  |problem here   pipes  not needed Call |Operator|10:33:14|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
6  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|19|BM451|202302|20  |This is also fine                        |Operator|10:33:14|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
```

Comment: Thank you Jared. This does exactly what I need in under a second on a production file containing nearly 69k records.

Comment: You're welcome; glad this solution worked on your 'real' data

Answer (score 1):

This solution would work on any awk:

```bash
awk -v c=9 '
BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"}
NR == 1 {
   totCol = NF
   print
   next
}
diff = NF-totCol {
   s = ""   
   for (i=c; i<=NF; ++i) {
      if (i <= c+diff)
         s = s $i
      $i = $(i+diff)
   }
   NF = totCol
   $c = s
} 1' file

IDS|STG   |STT|WRKLST  |AR|CD   |DT    |INDX|EVNT_MSSG                                |EVNT_SRC|EVNT_TM |TYP|DATE    |USR_ID|IDS_APP
1  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|14|BM404|202302|15  |This is some text                        |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
2  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|15|BM501|202302|16  |This is some more                        |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
3  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|16|BM502|202302|17  |This bit is all good                     |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
4  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|17|BM551|202302|18  |Yet more text                            |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
5  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|18|EM002|202302|19  |problem here  pipes  not needed  Call |Operator|10:33:14|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
6  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|19|BM451|202302|20  |This is also fine                        |Operator|10:33:14|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
```

Comment: How much time did it take for 69k records?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have fixed number of fields, here's one possible way to do it:

```bash
perl -pe 's/^([^|]*\|){8}\K.*?(?=(\|[^|]*){6}$)/$&=~s,\|,\\|,gr/e' ip.txt
```

This will replace `|` with `\|` in the problematic field.

`^([^|]*\|){8}\K` will consume first 8 fields and `\K` prevents this from being part of the matched portion.

`.*?` lazily match zero or more characters.

`(?=(\|[^|]*){6}$)` positive lookahead to ensure that the last 6 fields aren't modified.

The `e` flag allows using Perl code in the replacement section. In this case, the matched portion in `$&` is modified and returned as needed. Use `s,\|,,gr` to delete the pipes instead of escaping.

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
IDS|STG   |STT|WRKLST  |AR|CD   |DT    |INDX|EVNT_MSSG                                |EVNT_SRC|EVNT_TM |TYP|DATE    |USR_ID|IDS_APP
1  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|14|BM404|202302|15  |This is some text                        |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
2  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|15|BM501|202302|16  |This is some more                        |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
3  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|16|BM502|202302|17  |This bit is all good                     |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
4  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|17|BM551|202302|18  |Yet more text                            |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
5  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|18|EM002|202302|19  |problem here | pipes | not needed | Call |Operator|10:33:14|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
6  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|19|BM451|202302|20  |This is also fine                        |Operator|10:33:14|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}NR==1{split($0,arr)}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1){if($i=="|"&&arr[i]!="|"){$i=" "}};print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
IDS|STG   |STT|WRKLST  |AR|CD   |DT    |INDX|EVNT_MSSG                                |EVNT_SRC|EVNT_TM |TYP|DATE    |USR_ID|IDS_APP
1  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|14|BM404|202302|15  |This is some text                        |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
2  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|15|BM501|202302|16  |This is some more                        |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
3  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|16|BM502|202302|17  |This bit is all good                     |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
4  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|17|BM551|202302|18  |Yet more text                            |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
5  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|18|EM002|202302|19  |problem here   pipes   not needed   Call |Operator|10:33:14|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
6  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|19|BM451|202302|20  |This is also fine                        |Operator|10:33:14|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that both field separator and output field separator should be empty string, this leads to each field being one character wide. When processing 1st line (`NR==1`) I use [`split`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function to fill array `arr` with columns, then for each line I iterate over all fields and if I find field which holds `|` and corresponding field in `arr` does not hold `|` I change that field to space character. After processing fields I `print` line.

(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)

Comment: This will break badly when the input does not have fixed column widths. The question states the file is pipe-delimited, although the sample shown does look like fixed-column width.

Comment: It does look like fixed column widths but that's my own formatting, trying to make the example as clear as possible. These are not fixed column widths.

Answer (score -2):

```
echo '

IDS|STG   |STT|WRKLST  |AR|CD   |DT    |INDX|EVNT_MSSG                                |EVNT_SRC|EVNT_TM |TYP|DATE    |USR_ID|IDS_APP
1  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|14|BM404|202302|15  |This is some text                        |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
2  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|15|BM501|202302|16  |This is some more                        |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
3  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|16|BM502|202302|17  |This bit is all good                     |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
4  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|17|BM551|202302|18  |Yet more text                            |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
5  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|18|EM002|202302|19  |problem here | pipes | not needed | Call |Operator|10:33:14|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
6  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|19|BM451|202302|20  |This is also fine                        |Operator|10:33:14|0  |20230220|admin |3177098' 

|
```

> ```
> mawk NF=NF FS=' [|] ' OFS='   '
> ```

```
IDS|STG   |STT|WRKLST  |AR|CD   |DT    |INDX|EVNT_MSSG                                |EVNT_SRC|EVNT_TM |TYP|DATE    |USR_ID|IDS_APP
1  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|14|BM404|202302|15  |This is some text                        |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
2  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|15|BM501|202302|16  |This is some more                        |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
3  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|16|BM502|202302|17  |This bit is all good                     |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
4  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|17|BM551|202302|18  |Yet more text                            |Operator|10:33:13|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
5  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|18|EM002|202302|19  |problem here   pipes   not needed   Call |Operator|10:33:14|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
6  |ENRICH|Inc|complete|19|BM451|202302|20  |This is also fine                        |Operator|10:33:14|0  |20230220|admin |3177098
```

As long as one makes the assumption regarding

> - **all properly-formatted fields being left-aligned**,

then this shall work even for variable-width fields/columns.